# Selenium switchTo frame using Frameset

Tags: selenium

```
<frameset border="0" rows="25,*" frameSpacing="0" frameBorder="0" onbeforeunload="doUnload()" onunload="doUnload()" onkeydown="fn_KeyDown(event)">
    <frame name="link" scrolling="no" src="Links.aspx?FromWhere=DB" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" BORDER="0" target="_self">
    <script >
    alert('');</script>

                <frame id="Sub" src="../Home/Home.aspx?FromWhere=DB" scrolling="Yes"  name="Sub" >

</frameset>
```

How to switchto the frame here and perform operations in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to first frame    `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame[name='link']")));`

If you want to switch to the Second frame with name 'Sub'

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame[name='Sub']")));
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame#Sub")));
```